# Python Pandas Count of unique column values based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table (example below)

```
    kick_result kick_yards  kicker
50     MADE       28.0       X1
64     MADE       30.0       X2
75     MADE       27.0       X2
158    MADE       32.0       X2
259    MISS       46.0       X3
```

**For each value of kicker -**

I want to count how many field goals were made and missed (with %)

**For each value of kicker -**

I want to find the amount of field goals made and missed @ each range of yards <20, 21-30, 31-40, 41-50, 51+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your requirement has 2 parts:

1. field goals %, and
2. field goals in yard ranges,

let's solve it one by one.

### Part 1: Field goals %

We can use [`df.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) together with [`.value_counts(normalize=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to get it:

```
(df.groupby('kicker')['kick_result']
   .value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).round(2)
   .sort_index()
   .to_frame(name='Result_%')
).reset_index()
```

### Test Run

**Test Data Construction:**

To have a complete testing of the various requirements, I have **added test data** as follows:

```
    kick_result kick_yards  kicker
49     MADE       18.0       X1 
50     MADE       28.0       X1
51     MADE       38.0       X1
52     MISS       48.0       X1
53     MISS       58.0       X1
64     MADE       30.0       X2
75     MADE       27.0       X2
158    MADE       32.0       X2
159    MISS       32.0       X2
160    MISS       42.0       X2
259    MISS       46.0       X3
260    MISS       26.0       X3
261    MADE       56.0       X3
```

**Run code:**

```
(df.groupby('kicker')['kick_result']
   .value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).round(2)
   .sort_index()
   .to_frame(name='Result_%')
).reset_index()
```

**Result:**

```
  kicker kick_result  Result_%
0     X1        MADE     60.00
1     X1        MISS     40.00
2     X2        MADE     60.00
3     X2        MISS     40.00
4     X3        MADE     33.33
5     X3        MISS     66.67
```

### Part 2: Field goals in yard ranges

We can use [`pd.crosstab()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) together with [`pd.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to build a table with the yard ranges.

**Total attempts for all ranges are also included.**

```
pd.crosstab(index=[df['kicker'], pd.cut(df['kick_yards'],[0, 20, 30, 40, 50, np.inf])], 
            columns=df['kick_result'], 
            margins=True, margins_name='Total_Attempts')
```

**Result (*using the enriched test data*):**

```
                        kick_result  MADE  MISS  Total_Attempts
        kicker           kick_yards                              
            X1          (0.0, 20.0]     1     0               1
                       (20.0, 30.0]     1     0               1
                       (30.0, 40.0]     1     0               1
                       (40.0, 50.0]     0     1               1
                        (50.0, inf]     0     1               1
            X2         (20.0, 30.0]     2     0               2
                       (30.0, 40.0]     1     1               2
                       (40.0, 50.0]     0     1               1
            X3         (20.0, 30.0]     0     1               1
                       (40.0, 50.0]     0     1               1
                        (50.0, inf]     1     0               1
Total_Attempts                          7     6              13
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us chain with `cut` and `crosstab`

```
out = pd.crosstab([df.kicker,pd.cut(df.kick_yards,[20,30,40,50,np.Inf],include_lowest=True)]
                   ,df.kick_result,normalize='index')
 
out
Out[228]: 
kick_result            MADE  MISS
kicker kick_yards                
X1     (19.999, 30.0]   1.0   0.0
X2     (19.999, 30.0]   1.0   0.0
       (30.0, 40.0]     1.0   0.0
X3     (40.0, 50.0]     0.0   1.0
```

Comment: This works but I need this for each value of kicker - so this will only give me totals.

Comment: is there also a way to add total attempts to this frame?

Comment: @Gamecocks20 check margins in crosstab  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html

Comment: @BENY Shouldn't X2 have 3 made not 2?

Comment: @BENY - I am looking but keep getting errors when trying to implement the margins. I just want to add the corresponding count (attempts) for each category in the group

Answer (score 0):

Leverage `get_dummies`, `cut` and build a resulting `DataFrame`:

```
df['Att'] = 1

dfmm = pd.get_dummies(df['kick_result'])

cols_A = ['A20','A21-30','A31-40','A41-50','A51+']
cols_M = [x.replace('A','M') for x in cols_A]

df_att = pd.DataFrame(pd.get_dummies(pd.cut(df.kick_yards,[0,20,30,40,50,np.Inf],include_lowest=True)))
df_att.columns = df_att.columns.to_list()
df_att.columns = cols_A

df_made = df_att.multiply(dfmm['MADE'], axis=0)
df_made.columns=cols_M
    
dff = pd.concat([df,dfmm,df_att,df_made], axis=1).drop(['kick_result','kick_yards'], axis=1)
```

**Resulting DataFrame:**

```
  kicker  Att  MADE  MISS  A20  A21-30  A31-40  A41-50  A51+  M20  M21-30  \
0     X1    1     1     0    0       1       0       0     0    0       1   
1     X2    1     1     0    0       1       0       0     0    0       1   
2     X2    1     1     0    0       1       0       0     0    0       1   
3     X2    1     1     0    0       0       1       0     0    0       0   
4     X3    1     0     1    0       0       0       1     0    0       0   

   M31-40  M41-50  M51+  
0       0       0     0  
1       0       0     0  
2       0       0     0  
3       1       0     0  
4       0       0     0
```

**Aggregation from that DataFrame:**

```
dff.groupby('kicker').agg(['sum'])

       Att MADE MISS A20 A21-30 A31-40 A41-50 A51+ M20 M21-30 M31-40 M41-50  \
       sum  sum  sum sum    sum    sum    sum  sum sum    sum    sum    sum   
kicker                                                                        
X1       1    1    0   0      1      0      0    0   0      1      0      0   
X2       3    3    0   0      2      1      0    0   0      2      1      0   
X3       1    0    1   0      0      0      1    0   0      0      0      0   

       M51+  
        sum  
kicker       
X1        0  
X2        0  
X3        0
```